# getting the ratio across multiple rows by a given ID

Tags: postgresql

I have a (test) table:

```
  zip  | category | value 
-------+----------+-------
 17268 |        1 |    23
 17268 |        2 |    10
 17268 |        3 |    33
 10011 |        1 |    22
 10011 |        2 |    78
 10011 |        3 |    45
```

I want to output another table that shows, by zipcode, the percentage of the total values that the category 3 values comprise.

For example, the total values for zipcode 17268 is 66.  And for that zip category 3 values are 33.  So I want to assign to 17268 the output ratio value .5 (for 33/66).

I can run this command:

```
select zip, sum(distinct value) from ziptest group by zip;
```

To get this transformation:

```
  zip  | sum 
-------+-----
 10011 | 145
 17268 |  66
```

But now I want to divide that sum for each zipcode by the value of that zipcode's category 3 value.

Can anyone advise?

I suspect I'm looking for something like this:

```
select zip, (select value from ziptest where category = 3)/sum(distinct value) from ziptest group by zip;
```

or this:

```
select zip, sum(distinct value), (value where category = 3) from ziptest group by zip;
```

Comment: That seems like it's on the right track but outputs 22 for 17268 for example.  Should it be something like this? `SELECT zip, (value where category = 3)/sum(value) FROM ziptest GROUP BY zip;`

Comment: Oh! You are right. I misread the question

Comment: What I suggested is still wrong.  Do you know where to take this?

Comment: Just popped into an answer to finish this one off. There are a couple of ways to do it. The correlated subquery is a solid approach here. Alternatively you could join a subquery and then use the results in the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correlated subquery is a good route here. It's similar to your first attempt, but with the "Correlation" between the main query and the subquery:

```
select zip, (select value from ziptest where category = 3 and zip = zt.zip)/sum(distinct value) 
from ziptest zt 
group by zip;
```

Alternatively using a join:

```
 select zt.zip, zt2.cat3value/sum(value)
 from ziptest zt
     INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT zip, value FROM ziptest WHERE category=3) zt2
         ON zt.zip = zt2.zip
 group by zip;
```

Alternatively (and probably fastest) is using a case statement:

```
 SELECT zip, sum(CASE WHEN category=3 THEN value ELSE 0 END)/Sum(value)
 FROM ziptest
 GROUP BY zip;
```

Comment: Amazing.  Thank  you.

Comment: What exactly is happening where you assign zip to a new value? `zip = zt.zip`?

Comment: No! that is not an assignment. That is a predicate. It's similar in nature to a condition in an ON clause. It says "Only select records in this subquery where the `zip` is equal to the main query's `zip`." See where we alias the `ziptest` table as `zt`. It's sort of reaching up through the subquery to see what record it is that is performing the subquery and making sure it is only querying for that `zip` (this the "correlated" naming).

Comment: I've added a second option using a JOIN. You can see how they are very similar logic, but applied just a little differently. I've also added an option where you use a CASE statement, which is probably the best route since only a single pass is needed at the data. There's always more than one way to skin a cat in SQL.